# JS скрипт – замена даты на страничке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста нужно сделать скрипт, чтобы всегда выводилась дата воскресения текущей недели. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
let thisWeekSundayDate = new Date().getDay() !== 0 ? 
        new Date(Date.now() + (7 - (new Date()).getDay()) * 3600 * 24 * 1000) : 
        new Date();
```

`(new Date()).getDay()` - возвращает номер текущего дня недели.
1 - понедельник ... 6 - суббота, 0 - воскресенье

Берем timestamp текущего дня и прибавляем время в миллисекундах до воскресенья и снова берем дату от полученного числа миллисекунд

Comment: Спасибо! Спасибо!